# To get the annotation from StepDefinition in Cucumber

Tags: java, annotations, cucumber, java-11

I am trying to get the annotation: ("someid") used in step definition of cucumber in custom plugin implementation. How to get this? is it possible?

StepDefinition

```
    @Group(id="someid")
    @Given("today is Sunday")
    public void today_is_Sunday() {
        today = "Sunday";
    }
```

Custom Plugin class

```
package hellocucumber.listener;

import io.cucumber.plugin.ConcurrentEventListener;
import io.cucumber.plugin.event.*;

public class StepListener implements ConcurrentEventListener {


@Override
public void setEventPublisher(EventPublisher publisher) {
    publisher.registerHandlerFor(TestStepFinished.class, this::handleTestStepFinished);
}

private void handleTestStepFinished(final TestStepFinished event) {
    System.out.println("Status: "+event.getResult().getStatus());
    System.out.println("Id: "+ event.getTestStep().getId());
    System.out.println("Code Location: "+event.getTestStep().getCodeLocation());

    if (event.getTestStep() instanceof PickleStepTestStep) {
        PickleStepTestStep testStep = (PickleStepTestStep) event.getTestStep();
        System.out.println("Get Step:" + testStep.getStep());
        testStep.getStep().getText();
    }
}
```

}